# Is a Paraguay multiple-entry visa valid for more than 90 days in total?

Tags: visas, canadian-citizens, multiple-entry, paraguay

I have a friend from Canada that wants to visit me in Paraguay.  She might be staying a bit longer than 90 days (maximum stay allowed for tourist visa), and I was curious if it is worth it to suggest that she get a multiple-entry visa.

If a Canadian passport holder has a multiple-entry tourist visa, is she allowed to stay a maximum of 90 days **across all of her visits**, or is that just the limit **per visit**?

Comment: I had to include this as a comment, [just for an alternative](http://www.marksmayo.com/2010/07/24/hypothetically-how-to-break-into-paraguay-and-getting-a-blood-test-in-spanish/).  Hypothetically, of course ;)

Comment: Mark I took that same bus from Argentina, it didn't stop for visas for me either. I was in Paraguay before I realized it. Rather than going back and re-entering I continued on and exited Paraguay from Cuidad de Este airport. There were some questions but I explained what happened and the guy understood how the tri-state border bus works and gave me an exit stamp no problem. (I did some spiritual work while he was figuring it out thanking him in my mind for being so helpful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multiple-entry tourist visa allows you to enter and stay for 90 days multiple times, until the visa expires. There is usually a minimum waiting time between exit and re-entry, and that is different from country to country. For example, [with a Schengen or Russian visa, you can stay 90 days within a 180-day period from your first entry](http://www.norway.cn/Embassy/Visa-and-other-permits/Visa-News/Multiple-Entry-vVsas/); see also [this visa calculator](http://www.visacalc.com/).

I have found [a blog post that claims that there's a 5-day wait period between exit and re-entry for Paraguay](http://www.expat-blog.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=48413), but to be safe, your friend should call the [Paraguayan Embassy in Canada](http://www.embassyofparaguay.ca/eng/embassy/index.shtml) to confirm.

Comment: @todofixthis: I've added a source for multiple-entry.

Answer (score 4):

I have visited Paraguay about 5 times in the past two years on my UK passport. EU residents don't need to get a visa ahead of time.

1. It is very easy to do a visa run to Brazil or Argentina and get another 90 days
2. I believe it is easy to get extension to visa inside the country from the immigration dept
3. Most government rules in Paraguay can be "bent" or "changed" for the right fee. The country has one of the highest corruption rates in South America according to Transparency International. You have to decide if that makes sense to you and you might want to be aware of the situation what ever you decide because if an official is not giving you the answer you expect or want they might be looking for $20 to change their mind. It is the second poorest country in South America and this is how many official make ends meet.
4. I am not sure how Paraguay handles over stays but in Peru they just fine you $1 per day of overstay and it is no problem for re-entry, so you might look into that option too.

PS it is a beautiful country, amazing sights (esp the largest waterfall in Americas), friendly people and very relaxed pace of life. Low cost of living and lots of business opportunities and growth. Low taxes too. Traffic in Asuncion is a bit crowded and some bus drivers think their are in a Grand Prix so be careful crossing the street!